# Kernel Panic Not syncing : Fatal Exception

Tags: rhel, kernel, oracle-database

We have DB-DR on Remote Datacenter, And RHEL got hang twice in last two days, Yesterday it was showing just Black screen , And in today morning when i arrived at office again saw notification that DB-DR is hang. So by accessing through iLO i got this message

I'm not able to make up what is the issue

[image]

I checked for Tainted message in Logs and i got this

```
Nov 29 02:00:05 db-dr kernel: gsch_redirfs: unloading

Nov 29 02:00:05 db-dr kernel: gsch_redirfs: unloaded

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000028

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: IP: [<ffffffff811a4a5c>] pipe_write+0x8c/0x6b0

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: PGD cd1729067 PUD d352ee067 PMD 0

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: last sysfs file: /sys/module/ipv6/initstate

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: CPU 7

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: Modules linked in: gsch(U) redirfs(U) cpufreq_ondemand freq_table pcc_cpufreq bonding ip6_tables ib_ipoib rdma_ucm ib_ucm ib_uverbs ib_umad rdma_cm ib_cm iw_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr ipv6 ktap_102091(U) vfat fat uinput microcode iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support power_meter acpi_ipmi ipmi_si ipmi_msghandler sb_edac edac_core i2c_i801 i2c_core lpc_ich mfd_core tg3 ptp pps_core joydev hpilo hpwdt sg ioatdma dca ext4 jbd2 mbcache sr_mod cdrom sd_mod crc_t10dif ahci xhci_hcd hpsa wmi dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel:

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: Pid: 25778, comm: oracle Not tainted 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 #1 HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9/ProLiant DL380 Gen9

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff811a4a5c>]  [<ffffffff811a4a5c>] pipe_write+0x8c/0x6b0

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff880d3535fbb8  EFLAGS: 00010286

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: RAX: ffff880d3535c000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffff880d3535fd78

Nov 29 02:00:16 db-dr kernel: RDX: ffff880c439eacb8 RSNov 29 08:26:01 db-dr kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.

Nov 29 08:26:01 db-dr rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="3358" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start

Nov 29 08:26:01 db-dr kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset

Nov 29 08:26:01 db-dr kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu

Nov 29 08:26:01 db-dr kernel: Linux version 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Feb 21 00:53:17 EST 2017

Nov 29 08:26:01 db-dr kernel: Command line: ro root=UUID=ff7dde65-62ac-4dcf-bb04-65333fb3bfa4 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet

Nov 29 08:26:01 db-dr kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
```

Comment: I think you should take this to RedHat support. You are running RH, pay support and have the default kernel installed. This is a kernel bug. RH needs to fix it. Also you should make sure to be running the latest RH kernel - maybe it's already fixed there.